# How to get post from pure frontend AJAX (using only post ID)?

Tags: ajax, front-end

I need to show the various content of a post in a modal overlay.

How do I call Wordpress through AJAX from the front end (directly from a .js file), using the classic jQuery method?

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : ?
    data : {
        'id' : 247 <-- post ID
    }
    ...
});
```

This is NOT a PHP file, so no:

`admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_action&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);`

Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output your javascript via `wp_add_inline_script()`. This way you can set the post's id and AJAX URL before outputting the code:

```
wp_add_inline_script('my-js', '
    jQuery.ajax({
        \'url\' : '.admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_action').'
        data : {
            \'id\' : '.get_the_ID().'
        }
    });');
```

Note that you need to hook to an existing js file to be able to add inline script, so `my-js` must be a valid enqueued script.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your functions.php file:

```
function my_action() {
    $the_post_id = $_POST['id'];

    $output = json_encode( get_post( $the_post_id ) );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $output;
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action',        'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Enqueue the scripts:

```
function add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/build.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'app', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

The AJAX call from your js file:

```
$.ajax({
    url : my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        'action' : 'my_action',
        'id' : 214 // And whatever else you need to pass on ...
    }
}).done(function ( response ) {

}).fail(function ( err ) {

});
```